# Cheapest hosting for a node.js implementation?

Tags: linux, hosting, node.js

I'm looking for a Linux hosting company providing either easy node.js solutions, or cheap prices, or both.

I don't really have any experience looking for good hosting providers, so I'm looking for someone with experience or knowledge, rather than just googling and finding one.

I don't need to handle that much traffic at the moment.

But the key is easy node.js implementation.

Thanks!

**UDPATE:**

After poking around, it looks like [webbynode](http://webbynode.com/) has some pretty good support and a decent following behind it, and I'm really into their $15/month plan.

I'd still like some experienced input, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js is super simple to install and setup. If I were you, I'd just pickup a VPS at any hosting company (I prefer [linode](http://www.linode.com/)) and then you'd have a full linux machine that you'd be free to host other projects on as well.

Also, Amazon's micro ec2 instance is free for a year, allows for 10gb of S3 storage, and 10gb of EB storage - there are AMI's already out there, [such as these Ubuntu Server AMI's](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04/release/) that will fit on the 10gb EB storage limit (just make sure you install the elastic block version).

I love my free ec2 instance and plan on signing up for one using my gf's Amazon account after it's not so free in hopes to extend the free-ness.

I vote Amazon EC2 micro for as long as you can stay "free", and then moving to linode.

If you're afraid of administering a linux server, you could always install webmin as there is a debian package for it. Really helps me out (as a sysadmin) at work since I can create them an account on a server with webmin installed and the devs can actually figure out how to get their code running on it (our devs are devs with most of them having zero *nix experience).

Comment: Thanks for that!  I'll definitely be looking into these, as they seem like much better options.

Comment: Awesome! I'm happy to have helped. One more tip on EC2 - don't buy into their "elastic IP" item unless you're running something business critical. If your system is up 24x7 like mine, your dynamic EC2 IP will never leave you. I've had an A record for my domain pointed to my "dynamic" IP since November of 2010 and haven't had to change it since. Once you're up, just do a quick 'curl www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp' and there's your external IP.

Comment: Beast!  Free for one year is just epic, I'm so pumped.

Comment: Is it true that I'd have to run everything from a ssh client, though?  No GUI might be a little too much learning for me at the moment.  I'm trying to get it up fast AND cheap, but the speed is a little more important for me, at the moment.

Comment: grab webmin http://www.webmin.com/download.html :)
it's free, there are plenty of howtos around on getting it up and running, and there's a debian package for it too so you can install it on your ubuntu 8gb AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Joyent](http://no.de/) and [Nodejitsu](http://www.nodejitsu.com/).

Both offer a Heroku-style platform-as-a-service, which I have fallen in love with. I have too much to manage in life already, and these service require very little time to get up and going and also maintain.  Unfortunately both are in some stage of beta, but no harm in putting in a request for a beta invite and seeing what happens.